# How do I check the collision between a ball and a line

Tags: java, collision

I want to check if the ball and a specific line (zijde) collide. I want to do this by making the line function of the line. Than check if the coordinates that come out of the function are equal to the ball's coordinates. This is the code i'm using so far and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Zijde z is the line that the ball needs to collide with and has the functions getStartPoint (getStartPunt) and getEndPoint (getEindpunt).

```java
public Boolean CheckCollision(Zijde z)
{
    /**
     * y = ax + b
     * a = delta y / delta x
     * b = y - ax
     */
    double deltay = z.getEindpunt().getY() - z.getStartPunt().getY();
    double deltax = z.getEindpunt().getX() - z.getStartPunt().getX();
    double a = deltay / deltax;
    double b = z.getEindpunt().getY() - a * z.getEindpunt().getX();
    double yf = a * this.x + b;
    return yf == this.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no problems with the math, I'd change the last line to

```
return Math.abs(yf - this.y) < SOME_SMALL_CONSTANT;
```

since, given the imprecise nature of floating point arithmetics, your method would probably never return `true`.

I'd play with the value of `SOME_SMALL_NUMBER` to see what give you decent results.